# Import Google Cloud APIs to Android Gradle

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to use the Google Cloud API. And I followed the steps in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/language/v1) and added the `repositories` and `dependencies` to the Gradle file. However, in my Java file, when I added the import library line:

```
import com.google.cloud.language.v1.*;
```

It shows an error, saying that

> Cannot resolve symbol 'language'

I then rebuilt the project and the compiler says

> Error:(18, 1) error: package com.google.cloud.language.v1 does not exist

Seems like the API library wasn't added to the project. What should I do?

Comment: try this one import com.google.api.services.language.v1.*

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing `com.google.api.services.language.v1` instead.